# Google Analytics UTM Parameters and other Parameters

Tags: google-analytics

Suppose I have a URL like the following

`www.example.com/page?utm_source=Facebook&utm_campaign=affiliate&NID=999999`

What I am finding in `GA` is that when I have custom `querystring` parameters like the `NID` above, the `utm_source` is registering as direct traffic in real time analytics in GA.

I would expect this to read facebook.

Can you I have other custom querystring parameters and utm's still register

Answer (score 0):

utm_source and utm_medium are required parameters:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en

That said, the documentation is a little unclear:

"When adding parameters to a URL, you should always use utm_source, utm_medium, and utm_campaign. utm_term and utm_content are optional and can be used for tracking additional information"

Here's how it should be written:

When adding parameters to a URL, you must always use utm_source and  utm_medium.  The other three parameters are optional: utm_campaign, utm_term and utm_content.